Performance plugin for Jenkins - how to create the performance report even the user abort the job before it finishes
I'm working with Jenkins to run stress test (Jmeter and Perfomance plugin). In some cases, I need to abort the job, but in those situations the generation of the report by Performace plugin fails, because it does not find the .jtl file necessary for create it. How I can solve this?
PD: a few seconds after the JOB was aborted, the .jtl file appears in the workspace.

JMeter doesn't write the .jtl results file non-stop, it stores the data in chunks periodically.
If the default behaviour doesn't match your use cases you can add the next line to user.properties file:
jmeter.save.saveservice.autoflush=true

in this case any Sample Result will be written to the .jtl file immediately.
More information:

Results file configuration
Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide


Hi Ivan. It works! Thanks for your help
